# print ag-grid with ngx-print plugin, adding extra empty space inside table

Tags: ag-grid-angular, page-break-inside

I am printing pdf of ag-grid result table with some input texts inside a div using ngx-print, empty space is getting inserted below the table header.
Also width is not fit to the window as it is dynamically handled by this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
how do we handle on pdf

page-break-inside: avoid css didn't work. even ag-grid print as whole table's width got reduced to 0.
Plugin versions: "ngx-print": "1.2.1","ag-grid-angular": "^19.1.2","ag-grid-community": "^19.1.4", "@angular/cli": "^12.2.16",

for width problem I tried finding 1st row of ag-grid and enable the class on pdf using @media print.
It didn't work too.